# Given in-order traversal, how to convert to pre-order traversal? in complete binary tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree, traversal, inorder, preorder

Given inorder traversal, how can I convert it to preorder traversal? **Assume that the tree given is complete binary tree**.

Example:

Input: in-order: `{d, b, e, a, f, c, g}`

Output: pre-order: `{a, b, d, e, c, f, g}`

Answer (score 0):

If you dealing with complete binary tree then your array always contains `2^n - 1` elements.

Assuming this, it is easy to notice that the root in the in-order traverse will always be at index `(arrayLen / 2) - 1`. From here you can use recursive method on both side of the array.

Here is the solution in PHP (can be convert to any language):

```
function getPreOrder($arr) {
        $num = count($arr) - 1;
        if ($num == 0) // if only 1 element return it
                return $arr;
        $pre = array();
        $pre[]= $arr[$num / 2]; // first is the root (pre-oreder definition)
        $pre = array_merge($pre, getPreOrder(array_slice($arr, 0, $num / 2 ))); //take the left side
        $pre = array_merge($pre, getPreOrder(array_slice ($arr, $num / 2 + 1))); // take the right side
        return $pre;
}

echo implode(",", getPreOrder(array("d", "b", "e", "a", "f", "c", "g")));
```

This will output you: `a,b,d,e,c,f,g`.

Hope that helps!